# nginx hosting Angular and NodeJs projects under one domain

Tags: nginx, node.js

So I have:

- Angular (front-end, port: 4200)
- NodeJS (API, port: 3000)

I need to host them under one domain (example.com).

Should I use different nginx locations for this? For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

Or should I make 2 vhosts files?

I pretty much have no idea how to set this up, so any example for hosting 2 projects (in different directories) would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally you should use subdomains.